# On microblaze uclinux: put IP address to variable

Tags: bash, uclinux

Yes, this is related to [Putting IP Address into bash variable. Is there a better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829605/putting-ip-address-into-bash-variable-is-there-a-better-way) but nothing of the ideas there work for me on the microblaze uclinux. 
I wish to have my ip address of eth0 stored to a shell variable that I can write a script using it. I need alternative ideas how to do this.
ifconfig is available if that helps. 
I found that in the file /etc/config/dhcp0.conf the correct ip address is stored, here's the file's content:

```
1 192.168.10.102
```

How can I remove the 1 and space **without** using following commands

- grep
- sed
- cut
- this also does not work:  echo ${variable:2}

Comment: What about `sed`?

Comment: I guess it's too much to ask for `awk`.

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: What shell are you using? What features you can use depends a lot on the shell (and if `${variable:2}` doesn't work it's *not* bash, so the tag is wrong). The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020403/shell-script-execution-error-in-uclinux) suggest that it might be any of several much-less-powerful shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shell's `read` built-in:

```
read num ip </etc/config/dhcp0.conf
```

`$num` will contain the number at the beginning of the line, `$ip` will contain the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Assign ifconfig output of eth0 to array

`ifout=($(ifconfig eth0))`

Strip off everything before the semicolon of the 6th element of array and assign it to the variable $ethip

`ethip=${ifout[6]#*:}`

Comment: Although @Barmar solution works I tried this but I am getting an error: `/var/tmp # ifout=($(ifconfig eth0))`  
`sh: syntax error at 'ifout='`

Comment: It appears you are using sh not bash. What version of sh is it? 4.1 seems to work 

`sh-4.1# ifout=($(ifconfig eth0))
sh-4.1#
`

Comment: uuuh good question. it is on busybox 1.23. sh --version is an illegal option